# Default column sorting is not working for ajax data in datatable

Tags: jquery, ajax, sorting, datatable, datatables

I am using datatable to show my data and as I have a lot data and bringing all the data at once was taking a lot of time so I decided to use ajax from the datatable. Everything is working perfectly but default sorting function on column is not working at all. Clicking on arrow is sending ajax request. Is it not possible to use default sorting of the table?

```
var dataTable = $('#myTable').on('preXhr.dt', function(e, settings, data) {
    if (settings.jqXHR) settings.jqXHR.abort();
}).DataTable({
    destroy: true,
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    statesave: true,
    responsive: true,
    order: [],
    ajax: {
        "url": base_url + "ajaxcall",
        "dataType": "json",
        "type": "POST",
    },
    columns: [
        {
            "data": "srno", "orderable": true
        },
        {
            "data": "name", "orderable": true
        },
        {
            "data": "email", "orderable": true
        },
        {
            "data": "mobile", "orderable": true
        },
        {
            "data": "dob", "orderable": true
        },
        {
            "data": "city", "orderable": true
        },
        {
            "data": "state", "orderable": true
        },
        {
            "data": "country", "orderable": true
        },
        {
            "data": "zipcode", "orderable": true
        },
        {
            "data": "created", "orderable": true
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: This will be your server-side code - it appears you've called this `ajaxcall`.   What parameters does that receive for the "default" vs when you apply a sort?  What "default" are you expecting / getting?

Answer (score 1):

I am new to at SO, I have faced the same error! It seems that you are not specifying the default sorting information. Add the default params to your datatables while ordering them.

```
order: [[1, 'asc']]
```